# Bind events to mutliple appended data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery to post some data to a PHP script that processes it and then appends the echoed data. Now there is also some jQuery script among the data echoed it all works fine and well, as long as you don't send two instances of data to the script.

**Explanation:** Imagine that I have posted some text (Let's say A) to the processing PHP script which then inserts the data into the db and echoes the data along with a delete button; now the delete button works fine (it deletes and all..) but if I post another piece of text (Lets say B) to the processor (without reloading the page between postings) and echo out the data along with the delete button, only the first one gets deleted but the second one doesn't.

**Code representation**

Two text strings are posted (text1 & text2) without reloading the page, then a div gets appended; each of them has the delete button and the text, but the click event is attached only to the first delete button and no matter how many times I click the second delete button it doesn't do anything.

```
<div class="a">text1<div class="delete">X</div></div> // this one gets the click event 
<div class="b">text2<div class="delete">X</div></div> // this one doesn't
```

Below is the script used (simplified)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".delete").click(function () {
         $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Note:** the above javascript is echoed out twice since you post some text twice without reloading the page; the problem disappears when reloading the page.

---

For more clarification please leave a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're dynamically creating the elements, you have to use event delegation using `.on()`

```
$(document).on('click','.delete',function() {
    $(this).hide()
});
```

Also, it is better for performance if you replace `document` with a static parent selector to `.delete`

Comment: will try and notify you

Comment: @Mr.coder - weird.. whats the issue? Since you've accepted this as answer.. were you able to fix it?

Comment: yeah it worked but the problem is now different read this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231415/how-to-stop-toggle-from-taking-place-automatically-whilst-using-event-deligation