# how to stop toggle from taking place automatically whilst using event deligation

Tags: javascript, jquery

based on the answer received for my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229875/how-to-bind-events-to-mutliple-appended-data) i modified my code from

**this**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".edit-comment-mine").click(function () {
    var comm_id=$(this).attr('rel');
    $("#comment_update_cont"+comm_id).toggle();
});
});
```

**to this**

```
$(document).on('click','.edit-comment-mine',function() {
    var comm_id=$(this).attr('rel');
    $("#comment_update_cont"+comm_id).toggle('fast');
});
```

and it works but there is a problem again the div toggles on and then soon off without me clicking it again.So how do i stop it from doing that

Comment: try preventing bubbling. Into your callback function pass an event and then call event.preventDefault()

Comment: you mean `..function(event) {event.preventDefault();..` then i allready tried that

Comment: can you post an example on jsbin?

Comment: thats it the problem disapppears when the page reloads so it would be feutile

Comment: The problem is that your on click gets called more than once.

Comment: so how do i call it once?

Comment: have you tried `event.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: @Krishna just tried it didnt work

Comment: it would be nice to have this replicated on a jsfiddle so it would be easier for us to pinpoint the issue. otherwise, its more like shooting in the dark. Can you tell us what the `event.target` is for both the cases?

Comment: well if js fiddle would allow to execute php code then i would create a fiddle else its just impossible to replicate the problem